# WebServer - moving MySQL to another server on LAN for gaining more processing power?

Tags: mysql, web-server, local-area-network

I have website with high traffic hosted on dedicated machine. This machine running out of resources.

Will moving MySQL database to another dedicated machine on LAN give more resources to website (considering that MySQL queries are fulfilled by entirely other computer) or will it actually slow down more because data has to travel over network?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on a lot of facts. 
First of all queries will incur a slight penalty as it now has to travel  through the network. 
If the 2 machines are linked with a low latency and high enough bandwidth this should probably not effect it too much, which means it might improve performance.
Secondly if most of the resources are being used by MySQL and the new machine is not better then the old one, you might get a slower result.
In general, if your performance is bad at this moment and you are moving the MySQL server to a other machine which has better specifications (speed,memory,disk) and is linked with a fast connection you should expect speed up.